# Rails load YAML to hash and reference by symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, yaml, symbols

I am loading a YAML file in Rails 3.0.9 like this:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app.yml', __FILE__)))
```

It loads the all of the contents like hierarchical hashes, no problem.  The part I don't like is the fact that the hashes can only be accessed with single or double quotes but not a symbol.

```
APP_CONFIG['mailer']['username']  # works fine
APP_CONFIG[:mailer][:username]    # doesn't
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try using the [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) like

```
APP_CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app.yml', __FILE__))))
```

Comment: Thanks a million Rob.  only trick was in making sure Rails was already loaded.

Comment: Looks fine but I don't use ActiveSupport

Answer (score 37):

An alternative solution is to have the keys which you wish to access as a symbol prepended with a colon. For example:

```
default: &default
  :symbol: "Accessed via a symbol only"
  string: "Accessed via a string only"

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Later you can then access these like so:

```
APP_CONFIG[:symbol]
APP_CONFIG['string']
```

Note that I am using `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = "syck"`. Not sure if this works with `psych`. (Psych definitely won't support key merging as I showed in the example though.)

**About using `HashWithIndifferentAccess`:** using it has the side effect of creating duplicate keys: one for symbol access and one for string access. This might be nefarious if you pass around YAML data as arrays. Be aware of this if you go with that solution.

Comment: This should really be the correct answer. It is likely not obvious to anyone that YAML properties are not parsed as symbols by default.

Answer (score 29):

If you are working in Ruby on Rails, You might want to take a look at [symbolize_keys()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys), which does exactly what the OP asked for. If the hash is deep,you can use `deep_symbolize_keys()`. Using this approach, the answer is

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app.yml', __FILE__))).deep_symbolize_keys
```

Comment: `deep_symbolize_keys()` should handle nested attributes.

Comment: Good solution but it is the part of ActiveSupport. But it works in case of using Rails

Answer (score 21):

Psych (a.k.a. YAML) provides the keyword argument `:symbolize_names` to load keys as symbols. [See method reference](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/psych/Psych.safe_load)

```rb
file_path = File.expand_path('../app.yml', __FILE__)
yaml_contents = File.read(file_path)
    
APP_CONFIG = YAML.safe_load(yaml_contents, symbolize_names: true)
```

Answer (score 17):

This is the same from the selected answer, but with a better syntax:

```
YAML.load(File.read(file_path)).with_indifferent_access
```

Comment: If the file has an Array of hashes it won't work, because `with_indifferent_access` doesn't apply to arrays.

Answer (score 12):

There is another potential answer I discovered while digging around.

You can forgo HashWithIndifferentAccess.new by instead adding this to the top of your YAML files:

```
--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

then simply YAML.load like normal.  The only trick is that rails needs to already be loaded if you are doing this in your environment for use in initializers, etc. (like I am).

Answer (score 7):

1. Rails has a special method to symbolize keys.
2. You can use load_file method and get rid of File.read
3. Not sure if you need expand_path also, the default directory is rails root.

I'd write it that simple:

`YAML::load_file('app.yml').symbolize_keys`

Answer (score 7):

Just use appropriate option in your YAML parser.  For instance, `symbolize_names` in Psych:

```rb
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app.yml', __FILE__)), symbolize_names: true)
```

See RDoc: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using pure Ruby (i.e. no Rails), you could intermediately change to JSON format. The JSON lib's `parse` method can symbolize keys.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse

Here's what I mean:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.dump(YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../app.yml', __FILE__))), symbolize_names: true)
```

**Note**: This adds overhead of conversion to and from json.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably used to the params hash in Rails, which is actually a HashWithIndifferentAccess rather than a standard ruby Hash object. This allows you to use either strings like 'action' or symbols like :action to access the contents.

With a HashWithIndifferentAccess, you will get the same results regardless of what you use, but keep in mind this only works on HashWithIndifferentAccess objects.

So to make this work with YAML, you'll have to load the result of YAML.load into a HashWithIndifferentAccess, like so:

```
APP_CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(   YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app.yml', __FILE__)))   )
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't use `HashWithIndifferentAccess` just to avoid confusion and prevent inconsistencies in the way that it is accessed, so what I would do instead is tack on a `.deep_symbolize_keys` to get the whole thing in symbol key form.