# Access YAML keys as object or class member variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

I am making `config/locales/custom_error.yml` and loading it in `config/initializer/app_errors.rb`. It has the following contents:

**custom_error.yml**

```
app_flow:
  errors:
    fill_important_fields: "We recommend you to Fill this form "
```

**app_errors.rb**

```
APP_ERROR = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/locales/custom_error.yml")
```

Now in my application I can access keys like `APP_ERROR['app_flow']['errors']['fill_important_fields']` - I read [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072986/rails-load-yaml-to-hash-and-reference-by-symbol) but not the exact same as I'm asking .

**My Question**

I want to access these nested keys something like `class methods / members` like . `app_error.errors.fill_important_fields`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your hash to a Super-Hash! (with this light gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/shash/versions/0.0.7)

```
APP_ERROR = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/locales/custom_error.yml")
APP_ERROR = APP_ERROR.to_shash
```

Example:

```
sa = { first_key: { key_nested: 'value' } }.to_shash
# => #<Shash:0x000000099d0018 @hash={:first_key=>#<Shash:0x000000099cffa0 @hash={:key_nested=>"value"}>}> 
sa.first_key.key_nested
# => "value"
```

Comment: undefined method `to_shash'

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it came from a gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/shash/versions/0.0.7